# How to toggle visibilty of a button in ng-repeat tag in angular js

Tags: angularjs

The problem is the scope variables hides all list  elements instead that             element . The scope variable should only change one elements. is there any other way doing the same thing. i just want to toggle the visibility.

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="lstPractice in practiceList" ">
         <p class="coursepage-link">
          <a href=" #" ng-    click="AddAcitivity() " class="btn btn-primary btn- block" role="button" ng-hide="addAcitivityLogoVisisble"><i class="icon6 macicon-add"></i></a>
         <a href=" #" ng-click="RemoveAcitivity()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block " ng-show="removeAcitivityLogoVisisble" role="button"><i class="icon6 macicon-minus"></i></a>
       </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add and remove activity fn only chnages the boolean varibale to their respective values

Comment: if I understand, you want to hide one item and not all items? Have you defined, for exemple: lstPractice.visible ? and then: ng-hide="lstPractice.visible" ? with ng-click="lstPractice.visible=true"

Comment: Does an answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For each object in `practiceList`, set a value that defines which button should be visible:

```
$scope.practiceList = [
    { ..., show: true},
    { ..., show: false},
    { ..., show: true}
];
```

Here the first `a` is visible if `lstPractice.show` is **false**, else you will see your second `a`.

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="lstPractice in practiceList">
   <p class="coursepage-link">
      <a ng-show="!lstPractice.show" href="#" ng-click="AddAcitivity()" class="btn btn-primary btn- block" role="button"><i class="icon6 macicon-add"></i></a>
      <a ng-show="lstPractice.show" role="button" href="#" ng-click="RemoveAcitivity()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="icon6 macicon-minus"></i></a>
   </p>
 </div>
```

---

*PS: In this case, I would recommend using **[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)** instead of ng-show.*

Comment: you can also replace your function just by: ng-click="lstPractice .show=false" and ng-click="lstPractice .show=true"